# Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: MAC

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to execute the test in MAC OS. I have installed firefox( it is in Applications folder) and i tried to set binary path for firefox, I am not sure because I am new to MAC but still its not working..  I have attached the screenshots of setting firefox binary file but I am not sure whether it is correct. Please provide me solution to fix the problem.

[image: Setting up the firefox binary path in profile]

[image: location of firefox]

I got an error as below

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: MAC
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'ADMINISTRATORs-Mac-mini-2.local', ip: '172.16.105.81', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.3', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.<init>(Executable.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at myLearning.firstClass.main(firstClass.java:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can start firefox from command line:

```
open -a /Applications/Firefox.app
```